# Find the generating elements of the cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I have the following question:

Let $ (\mathbb {Z} _4, +) $ be a cyclic group, such that $ \mathbb {Z}_{4}= \{0,1,2,3\}$. Find the generating elements of $ \mathbb {Z}_4 $.

The feedback says that the answer is 1 and 3, but I don't understand how I should proceed to find that result. I thought it was just using the powers ($1 ^ 0, 1 ^ 1, 1 ^ 2$, etc.), but I can't go on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group is small enough to test each element by taking successive powers; since the group is additive, this amounts to taking *multiples* of the elements.

In general, though, as a hint, look at the greatest common divisor of the order of the cyclic group and the representative of the equivalence class that is each element of the group.

Comment: I understood! I was thinking of $\mathbb{Z_{4}}$ as a multiplicative group and it is an addictive group.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, @Thais.